# Gradle show test output for all subprojects or CLI

Tags: gradle

```
showStandardStreams = true
```

Great but how do I set it on all sub-projects that have the Java plug-in? Better yet, how do I turn it on for only **this** project from the command line? That way my team can do it without fiddling with the build code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set `showStandardStreams` to `true` for all sub-projects that have java plugin applied you need the following piece of code:

```
subprojects.findAll {
  it.plugins*.class*.name.any { it.toLowerCase().contains('java')
}.each { p ->
  configure(p) { 
    test {
      testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
    }
  }
}
```

It cannot be done from commandline. Also, have a look at a demo [here](https://github.com/Opalo/stackoverflow/tree/master/34793194).

Comment: Actually, can't I detect a system property and set it based on that?

Comment: @user447607 if that's solution fits, you of course can. You can also utilize project property `-P` - seems a better idea. I just meant that there's no default option.